# Rails: Render pages of Will_Paginate through Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a comment model that posts under a micropost model and they are both on the same page. The problem that I have is that when the comments paginate under the micropost the links lead to the second page of the microposts rather than the second page of comments but instead of redirecting to the second page I would like to render more comments that are paginated through ajax but I am confused with how to get to the nested route for this. Anyone have any suggestions for this? The routes part is getting to me. Here are the code for my micropost/comment section HTML. Also where do I have to insert the `respond_to do` section in which controller? Thank you!

**Micropost/Comment Section HTML**

```
<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
  <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
  <%= render comments %>
  <%= will_paginate comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
</div>
```

**User Controller - The page it is shown on**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comments = @micropost.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people go by the classic railscast on this:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

Note that now, for rails 3 you just include it with
`gem 'will_paginate'`
- and `bundle install` of course.  - instead of the longwinded
`gem 'mislav-will_paginate', :lib => 'will_paginate', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'`

Comment: I don't need `gem 'mislav-will_paginate', :lib => 'will_paginate', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'` if I have `will_pagniate` already?